# dotnet build SpecFlow cannot find generated feature.cs file namespace

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, specflow

I'd like to build my SpecFlow project on a build agent, but running `dotnet build` results in build error CS0234, because it is unable to find the Feature namespace of the generated features.cs files.

Building the project through Visual Studio works fine, but when I tried running `dotnet build` locally I encountered the same problem. The output is:

```
PS C:\repo> dotnet build .\EndToEndTests\
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: Features\CreditRisk.feature
  -> Using specflow.json
  SpecFlowGeneratedFiles: Features\CreditRisk.feature.cs
C:\repo\EndToEndTests\StepDefinitions\StepDefinitions.cs(1,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Features' does not exist in the namespace 'EndToEndTests' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\repo\EndToEndTests\EndToEndTests.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\repo\EndToEndTests\StepDefinitions\StepDefinitions.cs(1,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Features' does not exist in the namespace 'EndToEndTests' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\repo\EndToEndTests\EndToEndTests.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.60
```

Checking the contents of the generated feature.cs file shows that the namespace was generated:

```
PS C:\repo> cat .\EndToEndTests\Features\CreditRisk.feature.cs
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (https://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:3.9.0.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:3.9.0.0
//
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable
namespace EndToEndTests.Features
{
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

...
```

Since the Features namespace was generated I expect the build to succeed. Does anyone know why this doesn't happen?

Some additional info:

```
PS C:\repo> dotnet --version
7.0.203
```

```
PS C:\repo> dotnet tool list --global
Package Id                       Version      Commands
-------------------------------------------------------
specflow.plus.livingdoc.cli      3.9.57       livingdoc
```

Comment: The feature.cs files are generated using MS Build tasks now. Does the build work locally in Visual Studio or via `dotnet build`?

Comment: The file with the compilation error is `StepDefinitions.cs`. You haven't shown any of that file. What is the namespace in `StepDefinitions.cs`? Is there a `using EndToEndTests.Features` for `StepDefinitions.cs`?

Comment: Agreed with @JonathanDodds. We need to see StepDefinitions.cs - the entire file including the `using` statements at the top.